# reverse a character in array using recusion in C

Tags: c, recursion, reverse, c-strings, function-definition

this is my recursion function

```
void reverseArray(char *str,int len)
    {
        char temp;
        if(len==(0.5*len))
        {
            return;
        }
        temp=*(str+len-1);
        *(str+len-1)=*str;
        *str=temp;
        reverseArray(str+1,len-1);
    }
```

iam trying to reverse the charcters but when i send {'1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6','7'} to function i always get 7123456 only the last charcter become first the other not changing .

Comment: `if(len==(0.5*len))` Whats this?

Comment: You're switching two characters at a time, so `len` should decrease by two. Also, keep in mind you're dealing with integers and not floating points. And as you get closer to the center, `len` gets closer to zero.

Comment: Using the `[]` syntax for indexing would make the code much more readable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this call

```
reverseArray(str+1,len-1);
```

the second argument is incorrect. You have to write

```
reverseArray(str+1,len-2);
```

Also instead of this condition

```
if(len==(0.5*len))
```

it is much better to write

```
if ( len < 2 )
```

The function can look the following way

```
void reverseArray( char *str, size_t n )
{
    if ( !( n < 2 ) )
    {
        char tmp = *str;
        *str = *( str + n - 1 );
        *( str + n - 1 ) = tmp;

        reverseArray( str + 1, n - 2 );
    }
}
```

Or

```
char * reverseArray( char *str, size_t n )
{
    if ( !( n < 2 ) )
    {
        char tmp = *str;
        *str = *( str + n - 1 );
        *( str + n - 1 ) = tmp;

        reverseArray( str + 1, n - 2 );
    }

    return str;
}
```

Pay attention that the function `strlen` or the operator `sizeof`  returns a value of the type `size_t`. This type you should use to specify the length of a character array instead of the type `int`.

For example the last function can be called like

```
char str[] = "Hello World!";
puts( reverseArray( str, strlen( str ) ) );
```